# ¿Por qué no puedo correr una función con un rango como parámetro? en VBA para excel

Tags: excel, vba

He estado intentando realizar un clon de la función `DIAS.LAB` en excel que consiste en calcular la fecha pasados 45 días sin contar fines de semana y días festivos. Pero resulta que mi código si puede funcionar si lo corro como un sub y mandando a llamar a mis funciones, sin embargo si mando a llamar mi función desde excel solo me aparece `#valor` no se a que se deba esto.

otro inconveniente que tiene mi código es que al ejecutarlo desde el `sub` se modifica el valor de la casilla de donde tomo el valor a calcular.

```
Sub diasHabiles()
    Range("c2") = fechaFinal(Range("b2"), Range("b2"), Range("g2:g58"))
End Sub

Public Function fechaFinal(fechaInicial As Date, fechaRango As Range, diasFeriados As Range) As Date
    While diasPasados <> 45
        If (Weekday(fechaRango) = 7 Or Weekday(fechaRango) = 1 Or 
            diaFeriado(fechaRango, diasFeriados)) Then
        Else
            diasPasados = diasPasados + 1
        End If
    fechaRango = fechaRango + 1
    Wend
fechaFinal = fechaRango
End Function

Public Function diaFeriado(fechaInicia As Range, dias As Range) As Boolean
Dim rngAux As Range
Dim rngValue As Range
Dim Vbuscado As Range
Dim Vreferencia As Range

Set Vbuscado = fechaInicia
Set Vreferencia = dias

For Each rngAux In Vbuscado
    Set rngValue = Vreferencia.Find(what:=rngAux.Value, MatchCase:=True, lookAt:=xlWhole)

If rngValue Is Nothing Then
    diaFeriado = False
GoTo continue

End If
    diaFeriado = True
continue:
    Next rngAux
End Function
```

Lo que he visto yo por mi cuenta es que cuando pasa los valores a evaluarlos en la funcion diaFeriado en el momento que hace el `Set rngValue = Vreferencia.Find` el no encuentra el valor y solo pasa un nothing aunque si se encuentre en mi matriz de referencia. ¿sería necesario que pasara mi función a una matriz para después compararla con la fecha evaluada? Alguien podría orientarme o ayudarme a solucionar mi duda. ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sí que puedes llamar una función desde excel. El problema aparece cuando intentas acceder a las celdas pasadas como argumentos. Excel no permite acceder a celdas desde una Function o Sub creada en un modulo ya sea Private o Public. Puedes comprobar esto añadiendo en tu función fechaFinal un:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Verás que, aunque con error, la función es ejecutada. El fallo lo da la línea que trata de escribir en la celda pasada como argumento

```
fechaRango = fechaRango + 1
```

Desde un Sub esa misma función escribirá sin problemas en las deldas determinadas.

El código está bien pero se puede recortar un poco. Espero que no te moleste.
Lo primero es eliminar el primer argumento (**fechaInicial**)  de la función ***fechaFinal(...)*** porque no se utiliza en ningún momento.

```
Sub diasHabiles()
    Range("c2") = fechaFinal(Range("b2"), Range("g2:g58"))
End Sub


Public Function fechaFinal(fechaRango As Range, diasFeriados As Range) As Date
fechaRangoTmp = fechaRango
On Error Resume Next
    While diasPasados <> 45
        'Si no es fin de semana ni festivo cuenta dia
        If (Not Weekday(fechaRango) > 5 And Not diaFeriado(fechaRango, diasFeriados)) Then diasPasados = diasPasados + 1
    fechaRango = fechaRango + 1
    Wend
fechaFinal = fechaRango
fechaRango = fechaRangoTmp
End Function


Public Function diaFeriado(fechaInicia As Range, dias As Range) As Boolean
Dim rngAux As Range
Dim rngValue As Range
Dim Vbuscado As Range
Dim Vreferencia As Range
Set Vbuscado = fechaInicia
Set Vreferencia = dias

    For Each rngAux In Vbuscado
        Set rngValue = Vreferencia.Find(what:=rngAux.Value, MatchCase:=True, lookAt:=xlWhole)
        diaFeriado = Not (rngValue Is Nothing)
    Next rngAux
End Function
```

La simplificación de la sentencia ***If (Not Weekday...*** está basada en las leyes de **De Morgan** que permiten cambiar una suma por un producto negado.

```
NOT (A+B+C) = NOT A * NOT B * NOT C
```

La sentencia original, tal y como está escrita dice: Si A o B o C es 1 haz…, si no (else) diasPasados = diasPasados + 1

ELSE se ejecuta solo si la condición (A+B+C) está negada y como solo es funcional la parte ELSE podemos simplificar la sentencia y dejarla en una sola línea.

Cualquiera de las dos formas seria valida:

```
If Not (Weekday(fechaRango) > 5) And Not (diaFeriado(fechaRango, diasFeriados)) Then diasPasados = diasPasados + 1
If Not (Weekday(fechaRango) > 5 Or diaFeriado(fechaRango, diasFeriados)) Then diasPasados = diasPasados + 1
```

Podemos simplificar también:

```
(Weekday(fechaRango) = 7 Or Weekday(fechaRango) = 1
'por
Weekday(fechaRango)>5
'Si es sabado o es domingo = si es posterior a viernes
```

y

```
If rngValue Is Nothing Then
    diaFeriado = False
    GoTo continue
End If
diaFeriado = True

continue:


'por

diaFeriado = Not (rngValue Is Nothing)
```

Comment: Corrección de último momento referente a la función Weekday(fechaRango). Según la configuración de cada sistema el día de inicio de semana puede alterar el resultado.

Comment: Las celdas implicadas deben estar formateadas en modo fecha.